# Sorting an Integer array

Tags: java, array, sorting, binary-search

The program sorts the array from lowest to highest and outputs the index of the searched value:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Integer[] random = {6, -4, 12, 0, -10};
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(random));
    Collections.sort(list);
    Integer[] array = list.toArray(new Integer[list.size()]);

    int y = Arrays.binarySearch(array, 6);
    System.out.println(y);

}
```

This works as expected, but you can see that I had to use 3 lines just to sort the array, before being able to do a `binarySearch` on it.

Can this code be improved?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As you say, this is wrong. This

```
Integer[] random = {6, -4, 12, 0, -10};
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(random));
Collections.sort(list);
Integer[] array = list.toArray(new Integer[list.size()]);
```

could be replaced by

```
Integer[] random = {6, -4, 12, 0, -10};
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(random);
Collections.sort(random);
```

where `Arrays.asList` just wraps the array without making a copy. Even better would be

```
Integer[] random = {6, -4, 12, 0, -10};
Arrays.sort(random);
```

---

Also note that sorting something just in order to be able to use binary search once makes no sense.

Also note that

```
Integer[] random = {6, -4, 12, 0, -10};
```

uses objects wrapping the `int`, while

```
int[] random = {6, -4, 12, 0, -10};
```

would be much more efficient.

Answer (score 2):

Boxing the `int`s and creating a `List` are both superfluous. You can just [`sort`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort-int:A-) an array of `int`s.

```
int[] array = {6, -4, 12, 0, -10};
Arrays.sort(array);
System.out.println(Arrays.binarySearch(array, 6));
```

If your goal is to obtain the approximate rank of an element, it would be faster just to count the elements that are smaller.